# Using react context to protect a route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an auth context like this:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  userId: null,
  token: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});
```

I am wrapping my router like this:

```
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          isLoggedIn: !!token,
          token: token,
          userId: userId,
          login: login,
        }}
      >
<Router>
// Routes here
</Router>
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Auth Hook

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(false);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(false);

  const login = useCallback((userId, token) => {
    setToken(token);
    setUserId(userId);
    localStorage.setItem(
      "userData",
      JSON.stringify({
        userId: userId,
        token: token,
      })
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
    if (storedData && storedData.token) {
      login(storedData.userId, storedData.token);
    }
  }, [login]);

  return { token, login, userId };
};
```

In my protected route component I am just console logging my auth context token after having logged in like this

```
console.log(auth.token);
```

The protected route:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../shared/context/auth-context";

  const ProtectedRoute = ({ path, component: Component, render, ...rest }) => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(auth.token);


  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
          if (!auth.token)
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/admin/login",
                state: { from: props.location },
              }}
            />
          );
        return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

But first it logs false, and then the token.

So, whenever I go to the route I should have access to after logging in it redirects me to the login page, I assume because first it is false.

So, the first console.log value is false and then a second later the token is logged to console. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

The data is not saved by the time rendering takes place, store your token in localStorage and use it from there.

Comment: Thank you. The token is in local storage and I was doing it like that but I thought I would try take advantage of what I already had in context so I didn't have to write more code.

Comment: If you do that, you will not be able to store the token, like if for some reason user refreshes the page it will reset the state in context API, storing token in localStorage is the optimal solution. Even while using storage libs it's preferred to store in localStorage unless you are want to use some persistors, even in those cases I store token in localStorage to reduce the code (like query to Apollo for local token) ...

Comment: I am trying out the local storage option again which works but I have found that if I tamper with the token I don't get redirected. Also, if I just use google chrome dev tools and create a local storage key with the right name and provide a value of token which has any value, it still lets me access the page. So, it works but can easily be spoofed. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: That's how json web token works, for every request you make you send your token in header to your API which again verifies the token. So even if someone modifies the token, there is no way they can access something they shouldn't. You can inspect the localStorage for most of the websites they also store it like that. Moreover during early days of redux, the store was completely visible to anyone using redux dev tools

Answer (score 1):

Need to flip the logic of what you're rendering, i.e. Create a "smart" Route component that either returns a `Route` or a `Redirect`. This allows for protected route also working in a `Switch`.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../shared/context/auth-context";

const ProtectedRoute = props => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(auth.token);

  return auth.token ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: '/admin/login',
        state: { from: props.location },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I use this pattern with redux and the `connect` HOC, but there's no reason it shouldn't work with the context system (*redux uses it, afterall*).

If you are logging in and redirecting *back* to a protected route before the auth token is stored in your "state"/context then this component will "bounce" until the "state"/context is updated. Typically the logic that saves the token should wait until it's in "state"/context *then* redirect back to the page referrer (i.e. the `location` you pass in route state in the redirect) a user was trying to access.

Comment: Thanks for that Drew. I have implemented your code but when I try to go to admin/dashboard even after being logged in and confirming the token is in local storage it still sends me back to the login page...

Comment: @user8463989 How is your `AuthContext.Provider` computing the value it's providing? When you authenticate/login how are you updating the context value? Here's a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-auth-context-authenticated-routes-w2eyi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) I created when answering a similar auth issue. I want to note the context state and value provides a callback to update that state. If you're using localstorage then you may need to correctly "listen" for when the app is updating it [*localstorage*] so the context value can update.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I have updated my question and added the Auth Hook. Hopefully that helps?